# Is taking the address of a variable is legal while assigning it?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I want to do something like this:

```
void* ptr = some_function(&ptr);
```

Is this legal in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's totally legal. Beware that your some_function will need to have this signature :

```
void* some_function(void** param)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is well-defined. What would not be well-defined would be to dereference the pointer in `some_function`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is correct.

Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I was just wondering before I did it because it seems like all the fun things in C are undefined!